# Is there a solution for $(\frac{3}{x+y+z})^n+(\frac{3}{x+y+z})^{5-n}<2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Is there a solution for

$$\left(\frac{3}{x+y+z}\right)^n+\left(\frac{3}{x+y+z}\right)^{5-n}<2$$

where $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $x,y,z>0, xyz=1$.

This is the part of my attempts for my homework, that I stucked.

This is obvious $x+y+z≥3\implies \frac {3}{x+y+z}≤1$. But there is no any restriction for integer $n$. Therefore, I stucked. I tried Wolfram Alpha, even WA couldn't solve.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

By AM-GM inequality:

$$x+y+y\ge3(xyz)^{1/3}\Rightarrow \frac{3}{x+y+z}\le1.$$

The equality holds only when $x=y=z=1$.

It means that, for $0\le n \le 5$, we have

$$\left(\frac{3}{x+y+z}\right)^n+\left(\frac{3}{x+y+z}\right)^{5-n} \le 2.$$

You want to know if there is a solution for

$$\left(\frac{3}{x+y+z}\right)^n+\left(\frac{3}{x+y+z}\right)^{5-n} <2.$$

Think about the situation where you reach the sum equal to $2$.

Think on the interval $0\le n \le 5$.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: But, WA says $x=5,y=7,z=\frac {1}{15}, n=7$ then sum>$2$.

Comment: I am sorry, $x=5,y=3, z=\frac {1}{15}, n=7$. WA says sum greater than $2$.

Comment: Sorry, it is right. I will make an edit in my post.

Comment: Since you want to know if there is a solution for the inequality, you can think in the interval $0\le n \le 5$ and use the hint.

Comment: Can we say that the solution exist if and only if when $0≤n≤5$?